# How to get Attachment Ids from GoogleApi using flutter

Tags: flutter, gmail-api, email-attachments

I'm struggling to find out how to get a List of AttachmentIds of a Google Mail.

When I get a Mail from the Gmail Api I get the following Json Response:

```
{
  "id": string,
  "threadId": string,
  "labelIds": [
    string
  ],
  "snippet": string,
  "historyId": unsigned long,
  "internalDate": long,
  "payload": {
    "partId": string,
    "mimeType": string,
    "filename": string,
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": string,
        "value": string
      }
    ],
    "body": users.messages.attachments Resource,
    "parts": [
      (MessagePart)
    ]
  },
  "sizeEstimate": integer,
  "raw": bytes
}
```

As there is no Api Call to list all attached Files of a mail, I figure the information about the attachments must be somewhere in this response but I can't find it. Thanks for helping

Comment: There's no direct API to get all the Ids of attachments. You can try per id using [`GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/messageId/attachments/id`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get).

Comment: Thanks, but the problem was, that I don't have the ID's of the attachments.

Answer (score 0):

I did find out where to look for the information:
Google splits information like attachments and the full message body in parts that you can find in the payload of the message. 
I wrote a function that recursively adds all parts into a one level List and then filters out for attachment and message body:

```
//parts are recursively nested. To find the attachments, it seems necessary to
// iterate over all parts.
List _parts = new List();
void _getAllParts(_iterable) {
  _iterable.forEach((_part) {
    _parts.add(_part);
    if (_part['parts'] != null) {
      _getAllParts(_part['parts']);
    }
  });
}

_getAllParts(_mailObject['payload']['parts']);

_parts.forEach((_part) {
  if (_part['filename'] != "") _attachments.add(_part);
  if (_part['mimeType'] == "text/plain") _textPlain = utf8.decode(base64.decode(_part['body']['data']));
  if (_part['mimeType'] == "text/html") _textHtml = utf8.decode(base64.decode(_part['body']['data']));
});
```

I hope it saves anyone some time..